# SilverStripe $summary_field interupts label translation

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm using `public function fieldLabels()` in my DataObject to translate all field labels (as well as the labels for `$summary_fields`). This works fine for all fields, except one that has a value returned from a function (rather than value extracted from database).

**Summary Fields**

```
static $summary_fields = array(
    'Label' => 'Label',
    'Type' => 'Type',
    'getRequiredLabel' => 'Required'
);
```

**FieldLabels**

```
public function fieldLabels($includerelations = true) {
    $labels = parent::fieldLabels(true);

    $labels['Label'] = _t('UserForm.Label', 'Label');
    $labels['Type'] = _t('UserForm.Type', 'Type');
    $labels['Required'] = _t('UserForm.Required', 'Required');

    return $labels;
}
```

All fields are neatly translated through `fieldLabels()` except for **Required** because this has a custom value from a function rather than from data. Changing *getRequiredLabel* to *Required* fixes this.

Any way I can keep the value *getRequiredLabel* for the record fields and have the translated label in the top column?

[image]

Comment: Can you share your fieldLabels code please?

Comment: FieldLabels added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `$summary_fields` `getRequiredLabel` variable to `RequiredLabel` and use `$field_labels` to set the field labels.

```
private static $summary_fields = array(
    'Label',
    'Type',
    'RequiredLabel'
);

private static $field_labels = array(
    'RequiredLabel' => 'Required'
);
```

Then in `fieldLabels` the `RequiredLabel` column should be accessed with `$labels['RequiredLabel']`.

```
public function fieldLabels($includerelations = true) {
    $labels = parent::fieldLabels(true);

    $labels['Label'] = _t('UserForm.Label', 'Label');
    $labels['Type'] = _t('UserForm.Type', 'Type');
    $labels['RequiredLabel'] = _t('UserForm.Required', 'Required');

    return $labels;
}
```

You could also use the `Boolean` modifier `Nice` here to achieve the same effect.

```
private static $summary_fields = array(
    'Label',
    'Type',
    'Required.Nice'
);

private static $field_labels = array(
    'Required.Nice' => 'Required'
);

public function fieldLabels($includerelations = true) {
    $labels = parent::fieldLabels(true);

    $labels['Label'] = _t('UserForm.Label', 'Label');
    $labels['Type'] = _t('UserForm.Type', 'Type');
    $labels['Required.Nice'] = _t('UserForm.Required', 'Required');

    return $labels;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work oddly. If I rename everything to *Required* the translation works fine, but then a new issue arises. The required field is a boolean, and I have a function named **getRequiredLabel** (bad function naming, its not a label) that translates the boolean from 0 and 1 to more userfriendly Yes and No.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll have to give this more of a test. As a side note we can use `Required.Nice` in `$summary_fields` to make the results displays _Yes_ and _No_.

Comment: Ha, my getRequiredLabel function seems to be unnecessary then. Here's the whole code if you want to give it a test: http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/579ddd716a48f

Comment: And the lang file **nl.yml**: http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/579dde2fc7459
*Required* is translated to *Vereist*

Comment: I've tested this out and by using `$field_labels` to set the field labels this solution works.

Comment: I have no idea what is happening here, but it works. Would it be unfair to say that this labeling structure is rather oddly built in the cms core files?

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair call. From my experience always set field labels with `$field_labels` and never make `$summary_fields` an associative array. While making `$summary_fields` an associative array works most of the time, on some occasions it breaks stuff, like what we had in the answer before. I feel it is better to be safe and never make `$summary_fields` an associative array.